# изменения в таблице MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Есть таблица типа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли сделать такое: 1. Вырезать для слова например абрикос, из всех записей кроме первого абрикос из ячейки translation текст и добавить в конец колонки translation первой записи абрикос, тоже самое с яблоком и т.д. чтобы в итоге получилось так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

БД используется MySQL

Comment: при очень большом желании конечно можно. Но зачем вам это ? изначальная таблица у вас в нормальной форме, а результирующая получается денормализованной и далее с ней нормально работать в SQL практически невозможно. И зачем вам собственно строки с пустой второй колонкой. И вы хотите таким образом изменить данные в таблице или просто сделать такую выборку

Answer (score 0):

верно сказано, нормализация будет нарушена (1NF - использование произвольного списка значений в поле не допускается), в такой базе данных будет затруднительно например найти обратный перевод. 
Правильнее делать нужную выборку из базы, а не курожить по каждому случаю сами данные -

```
select DISTINCT word, group_concat(DISTINCT translation, '\n\n') from vocabulary;
```

Сделайте view из такого запроса и *profit*. Желателен индекс по полям word + translation.

Comment: Обратный перевод будет в другой таблице. Я хочу чтобы в колонке word были уникальные значения, а в одной из activity выводить данные из колонки translation по такому принципу  перевод1 перенос строки перевод2 и т.д.

Comment: Немного не так, уберите первый distinct и добавьте `group by word`. иначе групповая функция свернет все до одной строки

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, я 95% времени с postgresql работаю, могу действительно что-то попутать по mysql ))